# Codeigniter flashdata only appears after refreshing the page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter application which uses flashdata to store success or error states. 
On one of my servers, the applications works perfectly, everything is as it should be, but on another one, where my app is inside a subdirectory (root directory has ModX inside of it) doesn't work. All the flashdata is hidden, until you press F5 to refresh the whole page. Then the flashdata is shown.

I am seaerching everywhere for the solution, with no success. I suspected it's something with .htaccess, but to make my application redirect correctly I had to put `RewriteBase /test` to my .htaccess. Is it possible that my server requests are not working as they should?

Answer (score 0):

After set the flash Data redirect to the index function of the controller or at the starting of the function.
According to the CI  rule set the flash data and the redirect to the the starting of the function and then load the view.
I also face this issue and resolved after redirect it to the starting of the function.